# Cardinality question on vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose $F$ is a field and $J$ an infinite set. Is it then true that 
$\mathrm{card} \ J<\mathrm{card} \ F^J$? ($F^J$ the set of maps $J\rightarrow F$) I know that $\leqslant $, but is it true and why that we have $<$?

Comment: If $F$ has two elements, then $F^J$ is canonically bijective to the power set of $J$, and every set has a strictly smaller cardinality than its power set.

Comment: As long as you are saying that $0 = 1$ is not allowed then a field has at least two elements

Comment: Cardinal exponentiation is monotonic, so $|2^J|\le|F^J|$, because $2\le|F|$. So…

Comment: Why does the title mention vector space, and the tags linear algebra. I see nothing in this question that involves even the language of linear algebra. It would have been different (and the answer would have been different!) if $F^J$ denoted the free vector space with basis (indexed by) $J$, but the question makes clear that this is not intended.

Comment: $F^J$ is a vector space in the *obvious* way

Comment: @Rüdiger: I don't contest that, but the fact has no impact whatsoever on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from Cantor's theorem.